# I'm getting multiple erroe bars on the barplot, how to tackle this issue?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[after using facet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAchw.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5sgL.jpg)

I calculated se and put a script to show it on the barplot but it's plotted as multiple se bars

```
model.tables(data,type="means", se=T)
se <-2.85

p <- ggplot(data, aes(x=main, y=TGW, fill=sub)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=TGW-se, ymax=TGW+se), width=.2,position=position_dodge(.9))

p + scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired") + theme_minimal()
```

this is my data
structure(list(main = c("D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1",
"D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1",
"D2", "D2"), Rep. = c(3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L,
2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L), sub = c("E", "E", "C",
"B", "E", "B", "F", "C", "D", "A", "C", "A", "F", "A", "D", "F",
"B", "D", "B", "E"), TGW = c(53L, 55L, 53L, 57L, 61L, 54L, 47L,
55L, 41L, 61L, 56L, 66L, 50L, 59L, 50L, 55L, 53L, 45L, 59L, 55L
)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Welcome to SO! The most likely reason is that you have multiple obs. or rows for each pair of `sub` and `main`. For more help please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data best shared using `dput()`, e.g. run `dput(head(samer, 20))` and copy & paste the output into your question.

Comment: And as I already guessed you have multiple values for each `sub` and `main`, i.e. multiple `Rep.`s. You may try with `+ facet_wrap(~Rep.)`.

Comment: Or compute the mean/se of `TGW` by `sub` and `main`. But which approach is best depends on what's your desired result.

Comment: awesome, using facet tacled oerlaping but plotted each replicate independently, guess will compulte mean/se. THANKS